# Can we configure retry attempts on AWS Go SDK service calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, retry-logic, aws-config

AWS by default provides retries support on its service calls, which is usually set to a max of 3 attempts.

Can we configure the retry object to set retry attempts to 5?

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions about the same issue. You already have a question related to this here: [How can we avoid frequent 5XX errors and i/o timeout errors with AWS SQS service calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343275/how-can-we-avoid-frequent-5xx-errors-and-i-o-timeout-errors-with-aws-sqs-service)

Comment: I faced the problems at the same time but they were two independent questions that needed different solutions, hence posted it separately. However, will keep this in mind next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AWS provides support to configure their retry and timeouts features. Here are two ways to increase the max number of retries to 5 in AWS Golang SDK v2:

1. Configure the retry logic on the AWS Config object cfg and it can be used with various AWS service clients using NewFromConfig function

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRetryer(func() aws.Retryer {
    return retry.AddWithMaxAttempts(retry.NewStandard(), 5)
}))

client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

2. Configure the retry logic only for a specific AWS service client

```
customRetry := retry.NewStandard(func(o *retry.StandardOptions) {
        o.MaxAttempts = 5
    })

sqsClient := sqs.NewFromConfig(creds,
    func(o *sqs.Options) {
        o.Retryer = customRetry
    },
)
```

More info can be found at https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/retries-timeouts/ and https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/retry#hdr-Standard

Answer (score 1):

you can define a [custom retry strategy](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/tree/main/example/aws/request/customRetryer) for the SDK to use:

```
func main() {
    sess := session.Must(
        session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
            // Use a custom retryer to provide custom retry rules.
            Retryer: CustomRetryer{
                DefaultRetryer: client.DefaultRetryer{
                    NumMaxRetries: client.DefaultRetryerMaxNumRetries,
                }},

            // Use the SDK's SharedCredentialsProvider directly instead of the
            // SDK's default credential chain. This ensures that the
            // application can call Config.Credentials.Expire. This  is counter
            // to the SDK's default credentials chain, which  will never reread
            // the shared credentials file.
            Credentials: credentials.NewCredentials(&credentials.SharedCredentialsProvider{
                Filename: defaults.SharedCredentialsFilename(),
                Profile:  "default",
            }),
            Region: aws.String(endpoints.UsWest2RegionID),
        }),
    )
    // Add a request handler to the AfterRetry handler stack that is used by the
    // SDK to be executed after the SDK has determined if it will retry.
    // This handler forces the SDK's Credentials to be expired, and next call to
    // Credentials.Get will attempt to refresh the credentials.
    sess.Handlers.AfterRetry.PushBack(func(req *request.Request) {
        if aerr, ok := req.Error.(awserr.RequestFailure); ok && aerr != nil {
            if aerr.Code() == "InvalidClaimException" {
                // Force the credentials to expire based on error code.  Next
                // call to Credentials.Get will attempt to refresh credentials.
                req.Config.Credentials.Expire()
            }
        }
    })
```

[See the sample code here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/aws/request/customRetryer/custom_retryer.go)